# sed replace regex match group

Tags: bash, sed

I've a file:

```
import "aaaa/bbbb.ccc";
import "dddd/eeee.ccc";
import "fffff/ggg/hhhh.ccc";

BLBLBL
BL2BL2BL
```

And I want to replace the path of the import like this:

```
import "ooooo/bbbb.ccc";
import "ooooo/eeee.ccc";
import "ooooo/hhhh.ccc";

BLBLBL
BL2BL2BL
```

I've my regex with a match group of the part I want to replace:
`import \"([a-zA-Z]+\/|[a-zA-Z]+\/+[a-zA-Z]+\/)[a-zA-Z]+\.ccc\"`

But I don't know how to use it with sed to replace it with `ooooo/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```bash
sed -E 's,^(import ").*/,\1ooooo/,' file > newfile
```

*Details*:

- `-E` - enabling POSIX ERE syntax
- `^(import ").*/` - matches start of string (`^`), `import "`, and then one or more chars until the last `/`
- `\1ooooo` - replaes with Group 1 value plus `ooooo`.

The `,` char is used as a regex delimiter chars, so no need to escape `/` chars.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/gxaXYk):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='import "aaaa/bbbb.ccc";
import "dddd/eeee.ccc";
import "fffff/ggg/hhhh.ccc";

BLBLBL
BL2BL2BL'
sed -E 's,^(import ").*/,\1ooooo/,' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
import "ooooo/bbbb.ccc";
import "ooooo/eeee.ccc";
import "ooooo/hhhh.ccc";

BLBLBL
BL2BL2BL
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown example. I switched from `s///` to `s|||`.

```
sed 's|".*/|"ooooo/|' file
```

Output:

```
import "ooooo/bbbb.ccc";
import "ooooo/eeee.ccc";
import "ooooo/hhhh.ccc";

BLBLBL
BL2BL2BL
```